# How to declare a vector list of abstract class in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, polymorphism

I have several classes that inherit from one main class. For the sake of simplicity, I have over-simplified the class definitions to make it short and direct to the point.

## animal.h

#### main class which all other classes inherit from:

```
class Animal {
protected:
    string name;
public:
    Animal(string name);
    virtual string toString() { return "I am an animal"; }
};
```

## bird.h

```
class Bird: public Animal {
private:
    bool canFly;
public:
    Bird(string name, bool canFly = true) 
     : Animal(name)   // call the super class constructor with its parameter
    {
        this->canFly = canFly;
    }
    string toString() { return "I am a bird"; }
};
```

## indect.h

```
class Insect: public Animal {
private:
    int numberOfLegs;
public:
    Insect(string name, int numberOfLegs) : Animal(name) {
        this->numberOfLegs = numberOfLegs;
    }
    string toString() { return "I am an insect."; }
};
```

Now, I need to declare a `vector<Animal>` that will hold several instances of each inherited class.

## main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "animal.h"
#include "bird.h"
#include "insect.h"

// assume that I handled the issue of preventing including a file more than once
// using #ifndef #define and #endif in each header file.

int main() {

    vector<Animal> creatures;

    creatures.push_back(Bird("duck", true));
    creatures.push_back(Bird("penguin", false));
    creatures.push_back(Insect("spider", 8));
    creatures.push_back(Insect("centipede",44));

    // now iterate through the creatures and call their toString()

    for(int i=0; i<creatures.size(); i++) {
        cout << creatures[i].toString() << endl;
    }
}
```

I expected the following output:

> I am a bird
>
> I am a bird
>
> I am an insect
>
> I am an insect

but I got:

> I am an animal
>
> I am an animal
>
> I am an animal
>
> I am an animal

I know this has to do with the line 'vector creatures;`. It is calling the constructor for` Animal`. But my intention is to tell the compiler, that this` creatures`points to an array of`Animal`inherited classes, might be`Bird`might be`insect`, the point is: they all implement their own unique respective version of` toString()`.

What can I do to declare a polymorphic array of objects that are inherited from the same ancestor?

Comment: what you are facing is Object Slicing problem

Comment: @ThePhilomath would you care to elaborate more, or point me to where I can solve this issue?

Comment: Problem is with `creatures.push_back(Bird("duck", true));` You are creating a Bird object and copying that in the Animal object. One way is to create objects dynamically so that correct function call can resolve using vtable

Comment: Create a vector of pointer to Animal instead: `vector<Animal*>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is with `creatures.push_back(Bird("duck", true));` 
You are creating a Bird object and copying that in the Animal object. 
One way is to create objects dynamically so that correct function call can resolve using vtable.
Modify this part of your code and it will work fine.

```
vector<Animal *> creatures;

    creatures.push_back(new Bird("duck", true));
    creatures.push_back(new Bird("penguin", false));
    creatures.push_back(new Insect("spider", 8));
    creatures.push_back(new Insect("centipede",44));
```

**Edit:** Make sure to release the memory before `creatures` goes out of scope.

Comment: Since the pointers are created using `new` they have to be deallocated with `delete` once you are done with the vector. However, using a smart pointer like `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` avoids manual memory management.

Comment: @jignatius Yes you have to. Since the problem is not tagged with C++11 or later tags I can't suggest a solution using smart pointer.

Comment: Ok. I just thought I would point that to the OP.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use a **value** semantic (read about [object slicing](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/12-8-object-slicing/)). You must use pointers.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Animal
{
 protected:
  std::string name;

 public:
  Animal(std::string name) : name(name)
  {
  }
  virtual std::string toString()
  {
    return "I am an animal";
  }
  virtual ~Animal()
  {
  }
};

class Bird : public Animal
{
 private:
  bool canFly;

 public:
  Bird(std::string name, bool canFly = true) : Animal(name)  // call the super class constructor with its parameter
  {
    this->canFly = canFly;
  }
  std::string toString()
  {
    return "I am a bird";
  }
};

class Insect : public Animal
{
 private:
  int numberOfLegs;

 public:
  Insect(std::string name, int numberOfLegs) : Animal(name)
  {
    this->numberOfLegs = numberOfLegs;
  }
  std::string toString()
  {
    return "I am an insect.";
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>> creatures;

  creatures.emplace_back(new Bird("duck", true));
  creatures.emplace_back(new Bird("penguin", false));
  creatures.emplace_back(new Insect("spider", 8));
  creatures.emplace_back(new Insect("centipede", 44));

  // now iterate through the creatures and call their toString()

  for (int i = 0; i < creatures.size(); i++)
  {
    std::cout << creatures[i]->toString() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

prints:

> ```
> I am a bird
> I am a bird
> I am an insect.
> I am an insect.
> ```

I also recommend reading about [Sean parent Run Time Polymorphism](https://sean-parent.stlab.cc/papers-and-presentations/#better-code-runtime-polymorphism). The idea is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Animal
{
 public:
  struct Interface
  {
    virtual std::string toString() const = 0;
    virtual ~Interface()                 = default;
  };
  std::shared_ptr<const Interface> _p;

 public:
  Animal(Interface* p) : _p(p)
  {
  }
  std::string toString() const
  {
    return _p->toString();
  }
};

class Bird : public Animal::Interface
{
 private:
  std::string _name;
  bool        _canFly;

 public:
  Bird(std::string name, bool canFly = true) : _name(name), _canFly(canFly)
  {
  }
  std::string toString() const override
  {
    return "I am a bird";
  }
};

class Insect : public Animal::Interface
{
 private:
  std::string _name;
  int         _numberOfLegs;

 public:
  Insect(std::string name, int numberOfLegs)
      : _name(name), _numberOfLegs(numberOfLegs)
  {
  }
  std::string toString() const override
  {
    return "I am an insect.";
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<Animal> creatures;

  creatures.emplace_back(new Bird("duck", true));
  creatures.emplace_back(new Bird("penguin", false));
  creatures.emplace_back(new Insect("spider", 8));
  creatures.emplace_back(new Insect("centipede", 44));

  // now iterate through the creatures and call their toString()

  for (int i = 0; i < creatures.size(); i++)
  {
    std::cout << creatures[i].toString() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ objects are *values* with specific types. This differs from many languages where variables always hold references to objects, so they can hold references to derived objects just as easily.

If you copy an instance if a derived class onto an obhect of a base class, you get *slicing*: only the base class data is copied, and the type of the assignee is still that of the base class.

To achieve polymorphic behaviour in C++ you need to either use `std::variant` to specify the allowed possibilities, in which case the object will hold one of the options, and will switch type between them when assigned to, or you need to use a pointer to the base class, which can hold a pointer to any derived type, but you must then be wary of memory leaks. You do need to use `std::visit` or `std::get` to retrieve the values though.

If you are going to use pointers you should always use `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` to manage the objects in order to avoid memory leaks.

Code with variant:

```
int main() {

    vector<std::variant<Bird,Insect>> creatures;

    creatures.push_back(Bird("duck", true));
    creatures.push_back(Bird("penguin", false));
    creatures.push_back(Insect("spider", 8));
    creatures.push_back(Insect("centipede",44));

    // now iterate through the creatures and call their toString()

    for(int i=0; i<creatures.size(); i++) {
        cout << std::visit([](auto const& creature){
            return creature.toString();
        },creatures[i]) << endl;
    }
}
```

Code with pointers:

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>> creatures;

  creatures.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Bird>("duck", true));
  creatures.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Bird>("penguin", false));
  creatures.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Insect>("spider", 8));
  creatures.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Insect>("centipede", 44));

  // now iterate through the creatures and call their toString()

  for (int i = 0; i < creatures.size(); i++)
  {
    std::cout << creatures[i]->toString() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Code with `std::shared_ptr` is equivalent: just replace *unique* with *shared* everywhere.